# Setup an GitHub project on localhost

Tags: apache, github

i am new to github.

i want to setup https://github.com/Alanaktion/phproject project on my local machine.

I am using xampp.

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download a copy of the project by pressing the "Download Zip" button on the Github page. After that you should decompress the files into the root directory of Xampp. Depending on your operating system, the directory is located as follows:

XAMPP on Windows: C:/xampp/htdocs/

XAMPP on Linux: /opt/lampp/htdocs/

XAMPP on Mac OS X: /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/

Open the page in a browser, and fill in your database connection details. Detailed requirements and installation instructions are available at phproject.org.

Hope this helps

Comment: It's XAMP only on Mac, on Windows it's WAMP, and on Linux, LAMP.

Comment: Xampp can be installed in Windows, OS X and Linux. See https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html